# Out of heap space error though my code is not complex

Tags: java, heap-memory, comparator, extend

I've written this generic class as an extension of Arraylist(I know I'm not supposed to do this but I have to). The idea is to add generic objects and sort them. It compiles fine, and when I test it and add an object (from another class) it works fine. However when I add a second object, the program waits for about 30 seconds then returns "java.lang.outofmemory error out of heap space".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * extending to ArrayList
 */
public class SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable> extends ArrayList<E> 
{

/**
 * Constructing the super
 */
public SortedArrayList()    
{
   super();

  }

  public  void insertAndSort (E element){
  if (isEmpty()){
      add(element);
    }

  for ( int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
      E otherElement = get(i);
      if(element.compareTo(otherElement) > 0){
          add(i, element);
        }
      if(element.compareTo(otherElement) < 0) {
          add(i+1, element);
        }
    } 

}

}
```

Can anyone see why this is happening? Is there something wrong with my for loop?
Thanks

Comment: Well every time you call `insertAndSort` you're potentially *doubling* the size of the list. I suspect you didn't mean to do that. Have you debugged through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert` method is off. You need to find the correct position and add the element, not add the element for every element in the current `List`.

```
public void insertAndSort(E element) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        add(element);
        return;
    }
    int len = size();
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < len && element.compareTo(get(pos)) > 0) {
        pos++;
    }
    add(pos, element);
}
```

and the generic should be applied to `Comparable`. So this

```
SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable>
```

should be

```
SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, you are using `i < size()` as a condition. Each time you add a new item, the size will grow, too.

A [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is always sorted, by the way. But if you are bound to use an array list, you will need to remember the size before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will go on until i reaches its size. That will never happen, as you keep adding elements to it, making the size grow accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In `for ( int i = 0; i < size(); i++)` , when you add an element then size also increases - so same element keeps adding over and again.
Suppose, if you add 1 first and then try adding 2 then it will keep on adding 2 and list will become .........2,2,2,2,2,2,2.................,1 and causing the error.

Grab the size in a variable before using in loop.

```
 int length= size();
for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++){
  E otherElement = get(i);
  if(element.compareTo(otherElement) > 0){
      add(i, element);
    }
  if(element.compareTo(otherElement) < 0) {
      add(i+1, element);
    }
} `
```